# Suppress output of nslookup command in batch file

Tags: command-line, batch

Trying to cleanup my batch file...  Having problems with the following command still printing out some info:

```
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com') do (set PublicIP=%%a)
```

It keeps outputting:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
```

I've tried the following, but none work...

```
>NUL
>NUL 2>1
```

(and a couple others that I'm forgetting)

Comment: [DNS - NSLOOKUP what is the meaning of the non-authorative answer?](http://serverfault.com/a/413127/257436)

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a solution, changed things around a little bit.

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=2,3" %%a in ('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com') do (set PublicIP=%%a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that may help you, in my situation I needed that, so I can get my public IP without the non-authoritative answer alert:

```
FOR /F "SKIP=4 TOKENS=2" %%a IN ('"NSLOOKUP myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com 2>NUL"') DO ECHO %%a
```

Note the ' and " quotes in the brackets ;)

I found it by chance after two days of searching, as I read the following explanation about parsing the output of a command in for loops inside batch files: http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html